# Transversality: what is wrong with this counter example to persistence for small perturbations?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, dynamical-systems

Let $M$ and $N$ be differentiable manifolds in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, and let $p \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$. We say that $M$ and $N$ are transversal at $p$ if $$T_{p} M + T_{p}N = \mathbb{R}^{n}.$$ By dimension formula, if $M$ and $N$ are transversal at $p$, then $$n = \mbox{dim}T_{p}M + \mbox{dim}T_{p}N - \mbox{dim}(T_{p}M \cap  T_{p}N).$$

We also know that transversality persists under sufficiently small perturbations.

Consider this example. Let $n=2$, $M$ be the $x$ axis, $N$ be the graph of function $f(x)=x^{3}$, and take $p=(0,0)$, i.e. the origin. $M$ and $N$ intersect at $p$ but NOT transversally because their tangent spaces at $p$ coincide and hence the dimension formula above is not satisfied.

Now let us perturb $N$ slightly. Let $\epsilon>0$ be small and let $N_{\epsilon}$ be graph of $f_{\epsilon}(x) = x^{3} + \epsilon$. Then $M$ and $N_{\epsilon}$ are now transverse at point $p_{\epsilon} = (-\epsilon^{1/3},0)$, i.e. near the original point $p$.

Conversely, if we start with $N_{\epsilon}$, $M$ and $p_{\epsilon}$ we expect transversality to persist for small $\epsilon$, but again it fails for $N$.

So what went wrong in the above example? One thing I can think of is that the perturbation is of order $O(\epsilon)$ while the new intersection is $O(\epsilon^{1/3})$ away from the original point, hence not "close" enough...

Comment: If you start with $N_\epsilon$, "persistence for small $\delta$" will not include $N$: $\delta$ will be less than $\epsilon$.

Comment: Oh ok, how could establish an upper bound for $\delta$?, (I mean both for the specific case and in general) @MikeMiller

Comment: Oh ok, how could establish an upper bound for δδ?, (I mean both for the specific case and in general) @MikeMiller

Answer (score 1):

If an intersection of $M$ and $N$ is non-transversal, that means that you cannot be *sure* that the intersection persists under small perturbation. In your example, it's clear that the intersection will not disappear. However, if you would have chosen $N$ to be the graph of $g_\epsilon(x) = x^2 + \epsilon$, then it's clear that the intersection at $x=0$ will disappear for $\epsilon  > 0$.

In the end, it's a matter of [logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition): $P$ (an intersection is transversal) $\to$ $Q$ (this intersection persists under small perturbations) is equivalent to the contrapositive $\neg Q \to \neg P$, but not equivalent to the inversion $\neg P \to \neg Q$.